# t-SQL cartesian production of several tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I would like to get a cartesian product of several tables in SQL (which are actually only one column, so no common key). For example:

```
TABLE A

Robert
Pierre
Samuel

TABLE B

Montreal
Chicago

TABLE C

KLM
AIR FRANCE


FINAL TABLE (CROSS PRODUCT)

Robert | Montreal  | KLM
Pierre | Montreal  | KLM
Samuel | Montreal  | KLM
Robert | Chicago   | KLM
Pierre | Chicago   | KLM
Samuel | Chicago   | KLM
Robert | Montreal  | AIR FRANCE
Pierre | Montreal  | AIR FRANCE
Samuel | Montreal  | AIR FRANCE
Robert | Chicago   | AIR FRANCE
Pierre | Chicago   | AIR FRANCE
Samuel | Chicago   | AIR FRANCE
```

I tried CROSS JOIN, but I couldn't find an example with multiple tables. Is the only way to do it is nesting? What if we have 15 tables to join that way... it creates a very long code.

Thank you!

Comment: "a cartesian product of several tables in SQL" - are you aware of what this means? Cartesian products **do not scale**. The Cartesian product of two tables `a` and `b` has a cardinality of `a * b`, so if you're asking for 7 tables, that's `a * b * c * d * e * f * g` - and will probably have a higher cardinality than the number of atoms in the universe...

Comment: select * from t1 cross join t2 cross join t3 ... cross join t15. But why would you do something like that?

Comment: Having tables with a single column normally denotes a design flaw as well; I would hope that the data is overly simplified. Even if they are "validation" tables, they tend to be set up withn 2 column and the other tables reference the ID of the "validation" table rather than the value itself.

Comment: Tip: Learning to read the syntax documentation will pay off in the long run. [`FROM` clause plus `JOIN`, `APPLY`, `PIVOT` (Transact-SQL) clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) "explains" that a `<joined_table>` can be yet another `<joined_table>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply use:

```
select *
from a cross join b cross join c;
```

Do note that if any of the tables are empty (i.e. no rows), you will get no results.